# connecting Central to peipheral for change the colour of lights or on/off light

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I want to use `BLE` device for IOS which has on/off lights & coloured lights. I am connecting bluetooth using core bluetooth framework.

Now i want on/off or change colour of lights. How to do this from central  as app to peripheral as bluetooth device, what are all methods required to do this function ?

Comment: is the BLE device created by you ?

1)The BLE device can have services and characteristics.
2)You can access these services from the app and modify the characteristics
3)On BLE device When the characteristics values are changed glow your LEDs

Comment: no.i have data in string to change the colour of lights.i don't know how to write value which will change colour of lights.please help with code snippet

Comment: when i run my code app will come out of simulator,how do i test in simulator with BLE device.My code follows below

Comment: Please create a more specific question. Write what are you working on specifically and what part you are stuck at, what is the expected result and what is your current result. Also add all the relevant information such as what services and characteristics the device has. As for what you have written it would seem like you are asking for a BLE tutorial for the iOS implementation.

Comment: [mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]] options:nil]; how do i know my BLE device is 180A?

Comment: You can not test it on simmulator

Answer (score 0):

1) Scan with nil service id (if you are using in background you would need service id)

2) Scan

```
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil

                                                options:nil];
```

3) You would get devices in this delegate method

```
    - (void)   centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
        didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
            advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                         RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
// check advertisementData for service UUID
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

4) on successful Connection

```
- (void)  centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
    didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {

    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
}
```

5) on services discoverd

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering services: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    // Discover the characteristic we want...

    // Loop through the newly filled peripheral.services array, just in case there's more than one.
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
}
```

6) on retrieving charactesicts

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    // Deal with errors (if any)
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }


    // Again, we loop through the array, just in case.
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        // And check if it's the right one
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FFF1"]]) {
            scannedcharacteristic = characteristic;
            NSString *str = writeValue.length == 0 ? @"z" : writeValue;
            DDLogVerbose(@"Writing value %@", str);
            NSData *expectedData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [peripheral writeValue:expectedData forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
        }
        //        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.1. i m not getting ->[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FFF1"]?? 2. If i want this NSData *expectedData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [peripheral writeValue:expectedData forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse]; on button click?

Comment: What BLE Device are you using ? install an BLE services explorer app for eg (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/btlexplorer/id532751145?mt=8) and check the list of services.     (FFF1 is just an example, use NSLog to find UUID)

Comment: In my app using 3 buttons each button has particular data ,How to send data using writeValue: on each button click event?

Comment: Use a library to list properties and write characteristic http://kickingvegas.github.io/YmsCoreBluetooth/

Comment: how to send data from central to peripheral device ?